# Message Sent only with first word

Tags: php

Am trying to send SMS using PHP file. All email attributes are included on URL. The problem here is that , only the first word on the message is sent only !

I don't know why !

```
<?php
$url = "http://sms-gates.com/smspro/sendsms.php?user=myuser&password=mypass&numbers=".$_GET['mobile']."&sender=JobSeeker&message=".$_GET['msg']."&lang=en";

$link = fopen($url,"r");

while($res = fread($link,1024))
{

    echo $res;
}

fclose($link);
?>
```

Comment: Use `file_get_contents` instead of all the `$link` related stuff.

Comment: What value of `msg`, you are using to test ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to urlencode your parameters to replace spaces with %20 and so on.

```
$url = "http://sms-gates.com/smspro/sendsms.php?user=myuser&password=mypass&numbers=".urlencode($_GET['mobile'])."&sender=JobSeeker&message=".urlencode($_GET['msg'])."&lang=en";
```

Comment: No, he actually needs to read the manual for the SMS gateway API and see what he is expected to do.